# How do BeginsWith operations work in ESQL?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-sql

How do you perform a BeginWith SQL operation in **ESQL** syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these operators are same as in SQL: [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399359.aspx) and [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386895.aspx).